# Search button created keeps getting the compile error: Invalid qualifier. How to solve?

Tags: mysql, vb6

Why is my code not working. The error points to the rs.Open str, in the code

My code:

```
Public Sub Command2_Click()
Dim adoconn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As Integer
rs = InputBox("Enter the Client's IDNumber")
Dim str As String
Set adoconn = New ADODB.Connection
adoconn.ConnectionString = "DSN=..............."
adoconn.Open
str = "select * from Registration"
rs.Open str, adoconn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
```

Comment: you nedd to provide more information about the error / exception!

Comment: the error points to the rs.Open in the last line

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use your integer variable 'rs' both as an integer and as a recordset! In fact you don't actually use the output of Inputbox at all unless you've only shown partial code.

```
Public Sub Command2_Click()
Dim adoconn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim i as integer
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
i = InputBox("Enter the Client's IDNumber") ' i is not actually used
Dim str As String
Set adoconn = New ADODB.Connection
adoconn.ConnectionString = "DSN=gddb1;SERVER=000.000.00.000;UID=goldmacs;PWD=pass;DATABASE=gddb;PORT=3306;"
adoconn.Open
str = "select * from Registration"
rs.Open str, adoconn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
```

Comment: Not sure what happened to the code section there. It doesn't seem to handle comments